# Define class variable which refers to a previous class variable in python

Tags: python

```
class Foo(object):
    a = "/admin'
    b = Foo.a + '/hello'
```

`a` refers to a base path. And I want to define the class variable `b` based on `a`.
How do I achieve this ?

Comment: What do you mean by previous class variable or you want it to refer another variable of the same class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Foo(object):
    a = "/admin'
    b = a + '/hello'
```

Comment: since you are already inside Foo class so Foo.a is unneccessary. Hence Winston's solution replacing it with a. Voila!!!